# File Manager prepending "default" to all filenames

Tags: file-uploads, file-manager

I'm running EE 2.9.3 -- File Manager is adding the text "default" to the front of every filename when I upload files. I've looked in the File Upload Preferences but see nothing which would cause this. I am hesitant to solve this myself because that would involve updating core files, after spending some time to figure out where. However, if the only fix is to update a core file, I'm fine with that.

How is this happening and what can I do to stop it? Thanks!

Comment: Can you tell us what EE version you are running?

Comment: Yes indeed, I will edit the answer (2.9.3) into my question. Thanks!